# Cannot update 12.04 due to "Failed to fetch" warning

Tags: updates

I can't update my ubuntu 12.04. I tried it from terminal, update manager and also from the synaptic package manager. The error is

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 172.20.0.100:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 172.20.0.100:8080:
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's a problem with the server mirror you are using.

One possible option would be to open Update Manager; click the Settings button; under the "Ubuntu Software" tab choose a different "Download from" Server.

Answer (score 0):

Just like a browser can show a error message a Update Manger can also do it.

You can stop update it if theres nothing you can do.
by [image: remove a software source]

also chose another mirror can help you,maybe server you chosen was down.