# release upgrade fails

Tags: upgrade

Running on 13.10 and trying to make a release upgrade but getting this:

```
W:Failed to fetch 
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release Unable to find 
expected entry 'main/binary-ia386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong 
sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release Unable to 
find expected entry 'partner/binary-ia386/Packages' in Release file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release 
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-ia386/Packages' in Release 
file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release Unable to 
find expected entry 'main/binary-ia386/Packages' in Release file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Any hints how to resolve it ?

Comment: *binary-ia386*? There is no such architecture. Did you do something odd to your system? Try `grep -rH ia386 /etc`

Comment: there is ia but I don't know why it doesn't show up.

Comment: Did the grep turn up anything? What is the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`?

Comment: it shows up as i386 but why is it when do-release-upgrade changed to ia386 ?

Comment: And the grep command?

Comment: Nothing shows up when grepping /etc for ia386, all ppa's where purged and the sources.list was replaced with the default one.

Comment: Can you post the output of `apt-config dump`

Comment: Also `dpkg -l|grep ia386`

Comment: So in apt-config dump I can see ia386 shows up 
APT::Architecture "i386";
APT::Build-Essential "";
APT::Build-Essential:: "build-essential";
APT::Install-Recommends "1";  APT::Archives::MinAge "2";
APT::Archives::MaxSize "500";
APT::Changelogs "";
APT::Changelogs::Server "http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs";
APT::Architectures "";
APT::Architectures:: "i386";
APT::Architectures:: "ia386";

Comment: and `dpk -l|grep ia386` brings no output

Comment: Try `dpkg --remove-architecture ia386`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or change your server in system preferences > software & updates and then choose "download from:".

check if your updates are checked in updates tab (in software & updates) and check: Important security updates, Recommended updates and unsupported updates (check Pre-release updates if you want).

If there's a problem, post it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for hint, but I still doesn't work because of the same error. 
` http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-ia386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
`
I have tried to change servers - doesn't work. Tried to change nameservers in resolv.conf - no success.

Comment: Maybe in your proxy settings?

Comment: Maybe this site can help you:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/298177/a-failed-to-fetch-error-occurs-when-apt-get-update-is-run-how-do-i-fix-this

Comment: The error in the comment is different. BTW, it is highly advisable to purge all PPAs before doing an upgrade.

Comment: Couldn't it be because on the repo my architecture is missing ? 
_Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc_