# Reinstall ubuntu with a dual boot Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

Yesterday I tried to download some packages at my workplace, through their proxy server. The download failed and I received a 'proxyaddress' error.

Tried a few things to get past this error but nothing worked.

I rebooted Ubuntu which took me to the login prompt as usual.  When I entered my password the monitor went black and then I was presented with the login screen again.

I was able to login using a `ctrl_alt_f3` login.

I then tried doing dpkg, but I guess an Internet connection is required for fixing broken packages. Which brought me back to my original proxy issue.

I would like to reinstall/repair Ubuntu.  Repair is preferred so I can keep my data.  This is a dual boot environment with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Grub seems to work just fine but the recovery option under grub does not seem to work.

Any ideas on how I can repair my installation?

Comment: If you can get into Ubuntu via a terminal session as you say you can, you can probably repair whatever is broken versus reinstalling.  Looks like at least something got broken during the failed pkg download attempt.  First step will be to connect to the Internet at home or at a location that has a good Internet connection.  Your work proxy server (or proxy servers generally) may be blocked by where ever you tried to get your download from.

Comment: @jones0610 thanks for the reply mate. yes I tried doing that. I did try to run some recommended 'sudo' commands on terminal session but everytime I get a 'proxyaddress' (say for sudo apt-get update) error. But I am no longer connected to the same server, I am at my home where I do not require a proxy to access wifi and my laptop is connected to wifi (windows 8.1 is). I think the proxy settings are still present in ubuntu, any idea how I can delete the proxy settings?

Comment: Yes, based on your feedback you seem to be configured to go through a proxy even though you don't want or need to.  However, this is a separate question from the "how do I repair my installation" question.  Please open a new question on how to correct the proxy problem.  Or even better, have a look at the knowledge base for answers :)

Comment: @waltinator yes I hear you. Dual booting is just the first step to frustration. But the way I read this situation, the problem here is more about me miserably failing to download some packages in ubuntu because of proxy settings rather than the dual boot. I need to either delete the settings somehow and get the internet to work on ubuntu or reinstall ubuntu, maybe.

Comment: @jones0610 yes that is a good idea :)

Comment: Cool.  Once you get a solid Internet connection going we can start looking at how to fix whatever got broken during the download attempt.

Comment: @jones0610 I think I got the internet working with your suggestion. I can run sudo apt-get update without any proxyaddress error. I also tried installing a package via the terminal login and it was successful. Cool. But when I try to run dpkg I get an error 'Temporary failure in resolving in.archive.ubuntu.com'. I tried checking for package information in sources.list as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/298177/a-failed-to-fetch-error-occurs-when-apt-get-update-is-run-how-do-i-fix-this, but still it does not work.