# Install FFmpeg on Ubuntu 20.04 failed

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

```
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/flite/libflite1_2.1-release-3_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavdevice58_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavresample4_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/intel-gmmlib/libigdgmm11_20.1.1+ds1-1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you try the suggested commands? What's the output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Did you retry and the error persists? Check your DNS settings, are you in a restricted network environment?

Comment: Yes,I'm in a restricted network environment. Can you tell me how to check my DNS setting and set it?

Comment: Please edit your question with the requested info. Show us `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Please also include the entire output of `sudo apt install ffmpeg`. It doesn't do much good to give us bits and pieces of terminal output, especially when you don't tell us what command you used to get it.  Use the edit link to add these details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A "failed to fetch" error occurs when apt-get update is run. How do I fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298177/a-failed-to-fetch-error-occurs-when-apt-get-update-is-run-how-do-i-fix-this)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the same issue.

I found these error show because of the update source, you can resolve by changing update source.

see my blog https://itexp.blog.csdn.net/article/details/120638402  Failed to fetch:FFmpeg section

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1213455)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install alternative copy via snap as application package with all their dependencies.

```
# Enable Snapd
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd

# Install ffmpeg
sudo snap install ffmpeg

# Check installation
ffmpeg --version
```

I hope it could be useful